# Difference Between numpy.genfromtxt and numpy.loadtxt, and Unpack

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, numpy

I am curious to know the difference between the two functions alluded to in the title of this thread. From the website containing the documentation, it says, "`numpy.loadtxt` [is] [an] equivalent function when no data is missing." What exactly is meant by this? Does this mean, for instance, if I have a csv file that has a blank column between two columns containing data, I should not `numpy.loadtxt`?

Also, what does this mean,

```
"unpack : bool, optional
If True, the returned array is transposed, so that arguments may be unpacked using x, y, z = loadtxt(...)"
```

I am not quite certain as to what this means.

I'd appreciate your help, thank you!

Answer (score 16):

You are correct. Using `np.genfromtxt` gives you some options like the parameters `missing_values`, `filling_values` that can help you dealing with an incomplete `csv`. Example:

```
1,2,,,5
6,,8,,
11,,,,
```

Could be read with:

```
filling_values = (111, 222, 333, 444, 555) # one for each column
np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=',', filling_values=filling_values) 
#array([[   1.,    2.,  333.,  444.,    5.],
#       [   6.,  222.,    8.,  444.,  555.],
#       [  11.,  222.,  333.,  444.,  555.]])
```

The parameter `unpack` is useful when you want to put each column of the text file in a different variable. Example, you have the text file with columns `x, y, z`, then:

```
x, y, z = np.loadtxt(filename, unpack=True)
```

Note that this works the same as

```
x, y, z = np.loadtxt(filename).T
```

By default iterating over a 2-D array means iterating over the lines, that's why you have to transpose or use `unpack=True` in this example.

Comment: Another nice option that only `np.genfromtxt` has: if you want to have a structured array with fields, as it allows you to say `names=True` and the field names will be automatically generated from the first line of the file.

Answer (score 0):

In np.loadtxt each row in the text file must have the same number of values if not, an error will be thrown. You want to use loadtxt if you have no missing values. The method is also lighterweight, so if you can use loadtxt.

However if you have missing values and need more flexibility to modify your data use np.genfromtxt it provides much more functionality e.g
skip_footer, missing_values, filling_values, excludelist deletechars,replace_space,...

check out the numpy docs [genfromtxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt)!