# getting error to save the Matrix in txt file using numpy numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have written this code to make an array=>

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[[1,3],[1,4]],[[1,4],[6,9]]])
np.savetxt('test.txt',a,fmt='%d')
```

and getting this error =>

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy-1.11.2-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/lib/npyio.py",
>   line 1158, in savetxt
>       fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline)) TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not numpy.ndarray
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy-1.11.2-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/lib/npyio.py",
>   line 1162, in savetxt
>       % (str(X.dtype), format)) TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('int64') and format specifier ('%d %d')

How to save the array as an integer in file using numpy?

Comment: what kind of structure are you expecting for your output file? can you post what you want?

Comment: @roganjosh I want to save that matrix in that txt file

Comment: you have a 3d array, try save `a.reshape(-1, 2)` instead. `np.savetxt('test.txt',a.reshape(-1,2),fmt='%d')`

Comment: okk thanks for helping me. perfect @Psidom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an old thread on this problem

[Saving numpy array to csv produces TypeError Mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36552858/saving-numpy-array-to-csv-produces-typeerror-mismatch)

If you check, your array is a 3D array which is causing the issue

**1. If you translate it to a 2D it will work**

import numpy as np
a = np.array([[[1,3],[1,4]],[[1,4],[6,9]]])
np.savetxt('test.txt',a.reshape(-1,a.shape[-1]),fmt="%d")

**2. If you write one row at a time it will work too**

But this will have issues reading back

My suggestion, write it as dict/json and convert it to numpy after reading

Answer (score 2):

*I am not sure what kind of output you want...*

You can do this

```
F = open('test.txt', 'w')
for i in a:
    for j in i:
        line = '%s \t %s \n'%(j[0], j[1])
        F.write(line)

F.close()
```

Will give you

1    3

1    4

1    4

6    9

Comment: if I want to load this matrix How I will do this??

Comment: then you can use `numpy.genfromtxt('test.txt')`

Comment: please not that the comment from @Psidom will give you the same as my proposition in a more _numpythonic_ way

Comment: yes but you have posted that one is quite difficult to load the matrix from file. but if I use that one, is quite good cause there have a function loadtxt() in numpy. then why I will use this one

Comment: for the difference between `numpy.genfromtxt()` and `numpy.loadtxt()` you can look [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245593/difference-between-numpy-genfromtxt-and-numpy-loadtxt-and-unpack)

Answer (score 1):

```
%d format: a number is required, not numpy.ndarray
```

Essentially you can't use a format string on an object/class/what-have-you; its expecting a number, not an array of numbers

convert the array to a printable string. Similarly, you can't really save integers in files, only strings in files.

What you'll want to do is take each row in the array and write it to the file, something similar to this:

```
to_write = ''
for small_list in list_of_lists:
    to_write += ''.join(small_list, ',') + "\n"
my_file.write(to_write)
```

Comment: if I want to load this matrix How I will do this??