# Turn .txt file into matrix of ints in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix, file-io

If I have a txt file with the contents as such:

```
4 2 45 21
0 92 12 2
345 9 3 4
1 2 39 93
```

Is there a quick and easy way to turn this into a matrix of int?

Right now, I have accessed the file this way:

```
file = open(testFile, 'r')
data = []
for row in file:
    data.append(row)
```

This stores the data as an array where each line is a string. Instead of going through and converting the data types and then turning it into a matrix, is there a way I can immediately store this data in matrix form as ints as I read it in?

Comment: try `numpy`'s `loadtxt` method: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Comment: This worked. I tried genfromtext(), but my data came back as NaN's

Comment: Both `loadtxt` and `genfromtext` worked for me. Don't know why you're getting `NaN`s. @Zhiya why don't you add your suggestion as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay with having your data stored as a `numpy.ndarray`, you can use numpy's [`genfromtext()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) with the `dtype` flag set to `int`:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import numpy as np

text = """4 2 45 21
0 92 12 2
345 9 3 4
1 2 39 93"""

a = np.genfromtxt(StringIO(text), dtype=int)  #replace the arg with your filename

print(a)
#[[  4   2  45  21]
# [  0  92  12   2]
# [345   9   3   4]
# [  1   2  39  93]]
```

An alternative is to use [`loadtxt()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) instead of `genfromtxt()` as [@Zhiya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3346210/zhiya) pointed out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48833873/turn-txt-file-into-matrix-of-ints-in-python/48833901#comment84672317_48833873).

```
a = np.loadtxt(StringIO(text), dtype=int)
```

As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245593/difference-between-numpy-genfromtxt-and-numpy-loadtxt-and-unpack), both functions are basically the same except that `genfromtxt()` provides more options for dealing with missing data.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way of doing this is:

```
>>> for row in file:
...     data.append([int(x) for x in row.split()])
...
>>> data
[[4, 2, 45, 21], [0, 92, 12, 2], [345, 9, 3, 4], [1, 2, 39, 93]]
```

IMO, this is the most pythonic way

Answer (score 2):

for a nested list:

```
text = """4 2 45 21
0 92 12 2
345 9 3 4
1 2 39 93"""

[[*map(int, line.split())] for line in text.split('\n')]

Out[16]: [[4, 2, 45, 21], [0, 92, 12, 2], [345, 9, 3, 4], [1, 2, 39, 93]]
```