# Is there a way to change the value of a given number of values within a column of a text file with a python script?

Tags: python

I have a text file with multiple columns such as

```
1 0 0 

2 1 0 

3 1 1

4 0 0

5 0 1

6 1 1

7 0 1

8 1 0

9 0 0

10 1 1
```

I want to find a way that I can change a given number of values within a specified column. For example, I'd like to access column 3 and change the first 6 numbers all to 0 or 1. What would be the best way to do this?
I only ever want to change all specified values to a certain value and it will always be consecutive rows (such as rows 1 to 6 should all be changed to 0).

My coding background is shockingly limited but I figure I'll need to use a For loop somehow to go through the first six rows and append them to zeros. Just not sure on how to do this.

Comment: Please provide more context as to how and where you're storing these columns

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

with this code you can read .txt file as matrix and after this you can use for statement to control number 6 and change it. Then save it to .txt file :)

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.loadtxt('multiple.txt', usecols=range(3))
print matrix
```

if the code up there isn't work for u try this code below:

```
import numpy as np

c = open('multiple.txt','r+')
matrix = np.genfromtxt(c,delimiter=' ', usecols=range(3), unpack=True)
print(matrix)


   for i in range(0,7):
       if matrix[2][i]==6:
            matrix[2][i] = 0
```

matrix[column number][row number]

Comment: You might want to explain the difference between those two snippets and when to use which one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245593/difference-between-numpy-genfromtxt-and-numpy-loadtxt-and-unpack    difference between those functions

Comment: thanks. but how do I change the values in the third column using a for statement?